# Outlook "New Call" Dialog Box

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, outlook

I am writing an application in C++ which is a plugin for Outlook, is there a way to modify the functionality of the "New Call" window in Outlook? Perhaps with the Windows API? Or is this out the question? You can view the window by opening your contact list in Outlook, right clicking on the contact and clicking the button captioned "Call".

Thanks a lot,
Adam

Comment: What do you want to change and for what reason?

Comment: Modify the functionality of the dialog, so that when a call ends via putting the phone down, the right buttons are enabled and disabled.